# Sessions not working in Sinatra app when packaged with warbler

Tags: sinatra, jruby, warbler, jruby-rack

I've created a [simple sinatra app](https://github.com/genegc/warbler-sinatra-template), but can't get sessions to work when running it as an executable war.

I've verified that it works when run via "jruby -S rackup", but when run with "java -jar myapp.war", I find that the session is reset on each request:

```
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 running: controlPort=disabled
session: {"session_id"=>"75936d3d21367f5c1896e749ba401d7715e41a5fd01317484faa44d80c8afaea", "csrf"=>"60367cb6c5ead39b2669668ed28db3a1", "tracking"=>{"
HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>"9f3d63482f1fb48a317c5c9e2de6196f9cd239cc", "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"=>"66eae971492938c2dcc2fb1ddc8d7ec3196037da"}}
Jul 20, 2014 8:00:20 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 -  [20/Jul/2014 20:00:20] "GET / " 200 765 0.1670

session: {"session_id"=>"19d266ffb8ccb29108464961e68fa9e29f1c3b45e0097806b4cbc8db156d71d7", "csrf"=>"5ac12991c2ec8d4acf22180d79c494c2", "tracking"=>{"
HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>"9f3d63482f1fb48a317c5c9e2de6196f9cd239cc", "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"=>"66eae971492938c2dcc2fb1ddc8d7ec3196037da"}, "name"=>"john"}
Jul 20, 2014 8:00:31 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 -  [20/Jul/2014 20:00:31] "GET /login/john " 200 9 0.0240

session: {"session_id"=>"60f161941822b4f0fae9085db58fe9ea30e86d56dc16fff2ea5859bb4008c58f", "csrf"=>"7dd3977bef9fca9c7ed9b77fdc774657", "tracking"=>{"
HTTP_USER_AGENT"=>"9f3d63482f1fb48a317c5c9e2de6196f9cd239cc", "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"=>"66eae971492938c2dcc2fb1ddc8d7ec3196037da"}}
Jul 20, 2014 8:00:40 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
```

Other than setting sessions to be enabled, is there any special setup that is needed to have sessions work when the app is packaged with warbler and run as an executable war?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing special should be needed - I tried your sample and it worked fine.

it's probably a bug with the **jruby-rack** version you're using ... please try **>= 1.1.15**

also I would recommend to try out the jetty webserver (you'll find an option at *config/warbler.rb*) ... I'll try to make sure jetty is the default for a future Warbler version.

Comment: Thank you for validating. I've got it working now, still on jruby-rack version 1.1.14 - can't explain what was happening before.
Much appreciated.